# I get the Assertion failure "file_name != nullptr" but only in release mode

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++17

When I try to run the code in debug mode everything works fine, but when I try to run it in release mode I get the error "file_name != nullptr"(the error comes from fopen). I know what the error means, but I don't know why I get the error and how to fix it

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    String imageName("C:/Users/x/Desktop/pic.png"); // by default
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        imageName = argv[1];
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(imageName, IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if (image.empty())                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image);                // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
>-----------Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library----------------
>
>
>Debug Assertion Assertion Faild!
>
>Programm: C:\Users\x\...\myProgramm.exe
>File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fopen.cpp
>
>Line: 30
>
>Expression: file_name != nullptr
```

Comment: it should be string, not String, isnt it? Also in MSVC command line args are different for Release/Debug in the IDE interface.

Comment: string doesn't work. I dont use the command line args, i use the default imageName value

Comment: The path separator in Windows is a backslash. You are using forward slashes. That may or may not work.

Comment: i tryed it out with backslash but it does not work.

Comment: @Trifik when replacing with backslash, you need to add two to escape the backslash `C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\pic.png`  (just confirming that this is done)

Comment: @SaileshD yea i know (i had the problem a while ago)

Comment: @StepanYakovenko i figured it out. i added in the dependency the debug and release .lib files. i thought that MSVC will take the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you use the right dependency (.lib file) on debug and release mode.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit many .lib files having a "d" at the end of there name, wich stands for debud. in my case "opencv_world400d.lib" was for debug mode and "opencv_world400.lib" for release mode

Comment: _"only declared not initialized or defined"_ Not true, that is a definition and the string is default-initialised

Comment: _"the string get's a NULL pointer (nullptr) because it's not defined"_ Also not true. It's an empty, but valid string.

Comment: Either using debug instead of release (or vice versa) introduced UB, or in debug you're seeing a deliberate and wanted diagnostic that's silently hidden away in release (and thus you'd want to fix the bug) but the diagnostic wording is weird if it's just trying to catch an empty string